# How to do YARN role graceful shutdown on a Cloudera Manager datanode CDH 6.3.2

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Can not find answer on this question.

How to gracefully stop YARN role on a data node and wait till all running jobs on a datanode will finish with status success.

I know that in ClouderaManager you can decommission yarn role when you can stop it.
If I do YARN role decommission
The running jobs will fail with exit code killed or crash status.

Is this a safe way to YARN role stop on a data node?

Is this a graceful yarn role shutdown or where is other way to do this?
[all jobs have killed status after YARN role decommission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/879p4.jpg)

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YARN Graceful decommission will wait for jobs to complete. You can pass the timeout value so that YARN will start decommission after x seconds. If no jobs running within x secs then automatically YARN will start decommission without waiting for timeout to happen.

CM -> Clusters -> yarn -> Configuration -> In search bar (

yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanager-graceful-decommission-timeout-secs)
Set the value and save the configuration and do restart to deploy configs.
To decommission a specific host/more hosts

CM -> Clusters -> yarn -> Instances (Select the hosts that you want to decommission)

Click -> Actions for selected hosts -> Decommission
In case you want to decommission all the roles of a host then follow this doc
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cm_mc_host_maint.html#decomm_host

Answer (score 0):

This is documented poorly on [Apache website for hadoop 3.3](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/GracefulDecommission.html#configuration):

Create an XML file with NodeManagers you wish to decommission:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hosts>
  <host><name>host1</name></host> <!-- normal 'kill' --> 
  <host><name>host2</name><timeout>123</timeout></host> <!-- allows jobs 123 seconds to finish --> 
  <host><name>host3</name><timeout>-1</timeout></host><!-- allows jobs infinite seconds to finish --> 
</hosts>
```

Update your config(yarn-site.xml) to point to this file (No restart required)

```
yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path=[path/to/exculd/file]
```

run update: (initiate decomission)

```
yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes
```

Alternatively you could set a graceful timeout for all nodes:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanager-graceful-decommission-timeout-secs
```

Alternatively you manually set a graceful timeout:

```
yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes -g [timeout in seconds] -client
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and afford to help. In a Cloudera hadoop the process is a little different. I found the solution and test it on our cluster. I posted all steps above.  I hope it will help other people in future.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the issue.  I'm sorry I didn't frame the question in terms of Cloudera Manager.  Don't forget to mark your own answer correct if that is the answer.  If you found my answer helpful please upvote it.